# Unable to start SQL developer 4.1.5

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-xe

Can anyone please help me, My SQL developer unable to start. I re-installed Oracle database XE second time it stopped working. Earlier it(SQL developer) was working fine.

When I tried to open application it's not loading completely.

Comment: Why 4.1.5? Download & install the latest version (17.4).

Comment: Do you get the splash screen, and then it just freezes?